# I need to add exact same text before and after a specific character Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a script for which need the following.

Eg.

```
:Apple
:Ball
```

Need the above to be changed to

```
Apple:Apple
Ball:Ball
```

I have files that are a 100K in lines so need a efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    ^:(.*)$
Replace: $1:$1
```

### Demo

Comment: Why not `.+`?  Maybe some words have spaces between them.

Comment: What would be the solution, if I need the following

Apple: to Apple:Apple

What if the ":" is at the end and I need to add the word before the ":" to be pasted after too?

Comment: Maybe use the pattern `^(.*):$` with the same replacement as above?  If this doesn't work, I suggest asking a new question.